# best_in_place with more :activator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, best-in-place

I would like build a view, where it is possible to edit all listed element with just click on it, but would be great if there would be an Edit button as well, and it would activate the input field.

Without :activator the click event is the default, but with activator, this click event is not working. How could I turn on more activator? (In this case by clicking on text and clicking on button as well.)

My code:

```
%tr{id: "department_#{department.id}"}
  %td=best_in_place department, :name, type: :input, :activator => "#activator-#{department.id}"
  %td=link_to 'Edit', edit_department_path(department), id: "activator-#{department.id}", class: 'btn', remote: true
  %td=link_to 'Delete', department, method: :delete, class: 'btn', remote: true, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }
```

Thank you!

Comment: A little unclear what is happening. Do you mean that with :activator, the click on the activator element works, but a click on the main text element doesn't? Are you looking for a way to make the edit-in-place appear both when the text element is clicked AND when the activator element is clicked?

Comment: Looks, it is not possible... Hope I can figure it out...